# Comparing two excel tables results in exception 'Column 'F8' does not belong to table .'

Tags: c#, excel

I am using C# to compare two excel spreadsheets. I'm using the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' as a connection to the sheets. I convert the sheets to datatables and then the datatables to lists.

I am getting this exception when I run my code:

'System.ArgumentException: 'Column 'F8' does not belong to table .'

The exception is thrown at this line:

```
List<object> lst2 = (from d in sheet2.AsEnumerable() select d.Field<object>(a)).ToList();
```

This is strange because the first list does not throw this exception and both sheets contain the same columns (just different rows).

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: The error is clear. `F8` is an Excel cell address. The column is `F`. The row is `8`

Comment: What is the value of `a` when the error occurs? Where does that value come from?

Comment: The value of F8 is either 'C0603C102J5GACTU' or ''C0603C102J5GACTU' (i.e. they're the same). One has a leading ''' though that I can't seem to delete. So it's ''C0603C102J5GACTU'. I can delete the leading single quote and save the sheet but if I open up again it reappears when I re-open the workbook.

Comment: These refer to 'manufactured part' numbers of the components on PCBs. I doubt that's helpful though